# How to keep django rest API server running automatically on AWS?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I uploaded my Django API with Rest framework on AWS EC2 instance. However, I have to manually go to Putty and connect to my EC2 instance and turn API on whenever I want to use it by inputting `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

When I turn off my PC, putty closes and API cannot be accessed anymore on the ip address.

How do I keep my API on forever? Does turning it into https help? Or what can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I finally solved this. So when you close putty or a ssh client session, the session goes offline. However, if you run the session via daemon, the session continues in the background even when you close your clients. The code is

```
$ nohup python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
```

Of course you can use tmux or docker, as suggested by madi, but I think running this one code is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it live always by following means,

- connect your ec2 instance using ssh.
- Then deploy your backend (django) on that instance and run it at any port.
- Once run on your desired port, you can close the terminal,  please don't press ctrl+c so that your django server does not stop. you can just cross the terminal. it will be now running.

You can also run the django server on tmux (its terminal inside terminal). here is tutorial on tmux.
https://linuxize.com/post/getting-started-with-tmux/

One other approach is, you can deploy the django using docker container.

I hope you will come over your problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I think your first method is the easiest and I think I tried that. When I close putty, I didn't press ctrl+c but api goes offline.

Comment: can you connect using ssh in terminal? it will not close then

Comment: could you explain what you mean by connect using ssh in terminal?

Comment: like this, ssh usernamea@server-ip -p connection-port for example, ssh root@111.21.21.22 -p 22

Comment: i tried that on git bash but when I close the program, my website goes offline. Oh man

Answer (score 0):

You can use pm2.

Please install pm2.

And make a `server.json` file in the root directory of your django app to run  your app.

```
{       
  apps:            
     [{
       name: "appname",          
       script: "manage.py",
       args: ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8888"],
       exec_mode: "fork", 
       instances: "1", 
       wait_ready: true, 
       autorestart: false, 
       max_restarts: 5, 
       interpreter : "python3" 
     }] 
}
```

Then you can run this app with `pm2 start server.json`.

Your app will run on port 8888 .